# Facebook Graph API - Get past events from page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get past events of a page with the Graph API Explorer, I searched with Google and I find something but these didn't work:

- pageID/events?since=2010&until=now
- pageID/events?start_time>0

I also read the Facebook Developer Guide but it seems events returns only current events.

Do you know how to get these past events with Graph API Explorer? :)
Sorry for my english I'm italian ahah :D

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/#timepaging

Comment: I've just tried it (pageID/events?since=1357020000) but it returns:
{
  "data": [
  ]
}